# Inner classes definitions keeps asking for self argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Hello everyone hope you are well.

I am having some trouble trying to using the `self` variable for the `innerclass` however the `outerclass` is working just fine

```
#Assume this file is named classes.py
class outerclass():
   def __init__(self):
      self.ina = 10 
      self.inb = 20
      self.inc = 30
   class innerclass(object):
      def defined(self):
         self.vara = 40
         self.varb = 50
```

I call the class like this

```
import classes
test = classes.outerclass()
test.innerclass.defined()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#501>", line 1, in <module>
    test.innerclass.defined()
TypeError: defined() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Can anyone help me I have been trying to figure it out for a while.

Comment: "defined" is an instance method which must be called on an instance but "innerclass" is a class. This has nothing to do with "innerclass" being in another class.

Comment: At some point you need to call `innerclass()` if you want an instance of that class.

Comment: I am not sure what you 2 mean

Comment: @LaithStriegher "I am not sure what you 2 mean" => then you first have to understand the difference between a class and an instance...  [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about inner class.
`define` function is a method and you should use it for an instance not static.

Below code works fine. because, we called define over an instance.

```py
test.innerclass().defined()
```

`test.innerclass()` make an instance for `test.innerclass` class.

---

According to comments you want to get `vara` and `varb`

Try this.

```py
obj = test.innerclass()
obj.defined()
print(obj.vara, obj.varb)
```

Comment: the code I put is an example of the real code whitch has functions of the smbus module

Comment: The error you put in post says you should call `define` method for an instance of `innerclass`. it's not a static method.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: >>>test.innerclass().vara
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#541>", line 1, in <module>
    test.innerclass().vara
AttributeError: 'innerclass' object has no attribute 'vara'

Comment: `innerclass` has field or method named `vara`?

Comment: I edited the post, check the code, i think that's your answer.

Comment: I am trying to make a module soI cant have multiple objects